# How do I Solve this method?

Tags: java, methods

I have 3 Classes:Account,Customer and Main.the Main Class has the main method:
these Classes are the some parts of a programm.

```
    public class Account {
    private static ArrayList<Account> allAccounts=new ArrayList<>();
    private Bank bank;
    private int id;
    private int money;
    private int remainingDuration;
    private int interest;
    private Customer customer;

    public Account(Bank bank, Customer customer,int id, int money,int duration,int interest) {
        this.bank = bank;
        this.customer=customer;
        this.id=id;
        this.money = money;
        this.remainingDuration=duration;
        this.interest = interest;
        allAccounts.add(this);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Bank getBank() {
        return bank;
    }
  }
```

```
public class Customer {
     private static ArrayList<Customer> allCustomers=new ArrayList<>();
     private String name;
     private double moneyInSafe;
     private ArrayList<Account> allActiveAccounts;
     private int totalNumberOfAccountsCreated;
     private int negativeScore;

    public Customer(String name, double moneyInSafe) {
        this.name=name;
        this.moneyInSafe=moneyInSafe;
        totalNumberOfAccountsCreated=0;
        allCustomers.add(this);
    }

    public static Customer getCustomerByName(String name){
        for (Customer customer:allCustomers){
            if(customer.getName().equals(name)){
                return customer;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void createNewAccount(Bank bank,int money,int duration,int interest){
        totalNumberOfAccountsCreated++;
        allActiveAccounts.add(new Account(bank,this, totalNumberOfAccountsCreated, money, duration, interest));
    }

    public double getMoneyInSafe() {
        return moneyInSafe;
    }

    public void setMoneyInSafe(double moneyInSafe) {
        this.moneyInSafe = moneyInSafe;
    }

    public boolean hasActiveAccountBank(Bank bank){

    }

    private Account getAccountWithId(int id){
        for(Account account:allActiveAccounts){
            if(account.getId()==id){
                return account;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
public class Bank {
    private static ArrayList<Bank> allBanks=new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;

    public Bank(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        allBanks.add(this);
    }

    public static Bank getBankWithName(String name){
           for (Bank bank:allBanks){
               if(bank.getName().equals(name)){
                   return bank;
               }
           }
           return null;
    }

    public static boolean isThereBankWithName(String name){
        return allBanks.contains(getBankWithName(name));
    }

    public static int getAccountInterestFromName (String name){
         if(name.equals("KOOTAH")){
             return 10;
         }else if(name.equals("BOLAN")){
             return 30;
         }else{
             return 50;
         }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

So my question is How do I Define the hasActiveAccountBank method in Customer Class to Check Is there any Account with this Account id or not in Main Class. 
the part of the Main Class has a matcher that returns  Customer's name and the id so they are given.Here is the part:

```
if (!getCustomerByName(matcher.group(1)).hasActiveAccountBank()) {
                        System.out.println("Chizi zadi?!");
}
```

So How do i Write in the hasActiveAccountBank() argument?

Comment: The `class Bank` is missing in the code.

Comment: `return allActiveAccounts.stream().anyMatch(a -> a.getBank().equals(bank));`

Comment: Side issue: those static ArrayList fields should not be in those classes. They belong in other classes where it makes better sense to have them, and where they shouldn't be static.

Comment: Right, each Bank should maintain it's own accounts, not the central government.

Comment: I edited this Question